# Change Window Status message using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I wish to change the message on the status Bar of the IE Browser when my home page loads.
I need to do this using JQuery. I am using MVC 3.

I have tried to use Window.Status inside JQuery but I keep getting JS Errors.
Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status property does not work in the default configuration of IE, Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. To allow scripts to change the text of the status, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change preference to false in the about:config screen. (or in Firefox: "Tools - Options - Content -Enable JavaScript / Advanced - Allow scripts to change status bar text").

Comment: in IE10: Tools/Options/Security/(zone e.g. Internet)/Custom Level.  In the Scripting section: Allow Status Bar Updates Via Script

Answer (score 2):

```
 window.status = "my status";
```

Also, [Quoting MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.status)

> This property does not work in default configuration of Firefox and some other browsers: setting window.status has no effect on the text displayed in the status bar. To allow scripts change the the status bar text, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change preference to false in the about:config screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.status = "hello!";
```

do not capitalize them

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution in JQuery, if any.